# NSIS - Detect drivers available and let the user decide where to install an specific file (the license of the software)

Tags: nsis

What I need is:
After the software is installed, I need to identify the drivers available (Hard Disks, Pen Drives, etc), and the user can chose in which drive he wants to install the license of the software. When he chooses, a .txt file is created and it's written there the drive he choose (Example: C:).

My code without that feature is here:

```
  !include "MUI2.nsh"   
  !define NOME "S-Monitor"

  Name "${NOME}"
  OutFile "${NOME}.exe"
  InstallDir "C:\${NOME}"  

  ShowInstDetails show

;--- Paginas ---

  !define MUI_ICON Labels\SetupICO.ico

    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP Labels\Header.bmp
    !define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP Labels\Left.bmp

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES


  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_CHECKED
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Criar atalho na Área de Trabalho"
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "AtalhoDesktop"  


  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

;--- Idiomas ---

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"

Function .onInit

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Arquivos a serem instalados

Section "Instalacao"

SetShellVarContext all

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"  
  File /r Ficheiros\*.* ; LOCALIZACAO DA APLICACAO DO S-MONITOR

SectionEnd


Function AtalhoDesktop
createShortCut "$DESKTOP\S-Monitor.lnk" "C:\SMonitor.exe"
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

The user [smilepleeeaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1986779/smilepleeeaz) helped me at another question, and that can also be used to answered this.

The code with the feature that I wanted is down below:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh" 
  !include FileFunc.nsh
  !insertmacro GetDrives

  var newCheckBox

  !define NOME "S-Monitor"

  Name "${NOME}"
  OutFile "${NOME}.exe"
  InstallDir "C:\${NOME}"  

  ShowInstDetails show
  AllowRootDirInstall true

;--- Paginas ---

  !define MUI_ICON Labels\SetupICO.ico

    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
    !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP Labels\Header.bmp
    !define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP Labels\Left.bmp

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  Page Custom CustomCreate CustomLeave

  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_CHECKED
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Criar atalho na Área de Trabalho"
    !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "AtalhoDesktop"  

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW showNewCheckbox
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE launchNewLink

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

;--- Idiomas ---

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"

Function .onInit

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
  InitPluginsDir
         GetTempFileName $0
         Rename $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini'

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Arquivos a serem instalados

Section "Instalacao"

SetShellVarContext all

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"  
  File /r Ficheiros\*.* ; LOCALIZACAO DA APLICACAO DO S-MONITOR

  MessageBox MB_OK "O software BDE (Borland Database Engine) será instalado agora"
  ExecWait "Ficheiros\bde_install_Win7_32_e_64.exe"

  FileOpen $1 '$INSTDIR\S-monitor.cpy' w
  FileWrite $1 "CPY Location=C:\S-Monitor.cpy"
  FileClose $1

  writeUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe

SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"

MessageBox MB_YESNO "Deseja desinstalar o S-Monitor?" IDYES true IDNO false
true:
  SetShellVarContext all
  delete $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe
  RMDir /R /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR
  Goto +2
false:
MessageBox MB_OK "Desinstalação cancelada."
SectionEnd



Function AtalhoDesktop
createShortCut "$DESKTOP\S-Monitor.lnk" "C:\SMonitor.exe"
FunctionEnd

Function showNewCheckbox
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 120u 110u 100% 10u "&Iniciar o S-Monitor ao terminar a instalação"
Pop $newCheckBox
FunctionEnd

Function launchNewLink
${NSD_GetState} $newCheckBox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    Exec "C:\S-Monitor\Smonitor.exe"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function CustomCreate
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Settings' 'NumFields' '6'

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Type' 'Label'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Left' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Top' '5'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Right' '-6'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Bottom' '17'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 1' 'Text' \
         'Selecione o drive a ser instalada a licensa do S-Monitor:'

         StrCpy $R2 0
         StrCpy $R0 ''
         ${GetDrives} "HDD+FDD" GetDrivesCallBack

         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Type' 'DropList'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Left' '30'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Top' '26'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Right' '-31'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Bottom' '100'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'Flags' 'Notify'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State' '$R1'
         WriteIniStr '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'ListItems' '$R0'

         push $0
         InstallOptions::Dialog '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini'
         pop $0
         pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function CustomLeave
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Settings' 'State'
        StrCmp $0 '2' 0 next
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        strcpy $R0  $0
        StrCpy $0 $0 3
        FileOpen $1 '$INSTDIR\S-monitor.cpy' w
        FileWrite $1 "CPY Location=$R0S-Monitor.cpy"
        FileClose $1

        Abort
     next:
        ReadIniStr $0 '$PLUGINSDIR\custom.ini' 'Field 2' 'State'
        StrCpy '$INSTDIR' '$0'
FunctionEnd

Function GetDrivesCallBack
         StrCmp $R2 '0' 0 next
         StrCpy $R3 '$R4'
         StrCpy $R1 '$9'
         IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1
      next:
         StrCpy $R0 '$R0$9|'
         Push $0
FunctionEnd
```